# Alias multiple $match conditions on single field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been working on this for a while now with different combinations of 
$project, $match, $unwind in the Mongodb aggregate pipeline. My data is like:

```
{
    "flow":[
        {"y":1},
        {"y":69696},
        {"y":3}
    ]
}
{
    "flow":[
        {"y":4},
        {"y":69632},
        {"y":6},
        {"y":7},
        {"y":8}
    ]
}
```

I want to group the flow array elements depending on whether or not flow.y has the 16th bit set. I want to return the sum of the value (without the bit set) and the count of matching elements. So for the sample above I want to retrieve:

```
[  
   {  "bitset": {
              "_id":null,
              "count":2,
              "y_total":8256
          },
       "bitunset": {
              "_id":null,
              "count":6,
              "y_total":29
          },
   }
]
```

I can retrieve the information in two separate aggregate calls but would like to combine them.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: "$flow"}},
  {$match: {"flow.y": { $bitsAllSet: 65536 }}},
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    y_total: {$sum: "$flow.y"}
  }}
```

I have also tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: "$flow"}},
  {$match: {$or: [{"flow.y": { $bitsAllSet: 65536 }},
                  {"flow.y": { $bitsAllClear: 65536 }}]}},
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    y_total: {$sum: "$flow.y"}
  }}
```

which would be fine if I could alias the results from the $or operator.
**db version v3.6.5**

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: $cond would be useful if I could specify two different return fieldnames rather than two different values. I've tried {$cond: [{"flow.y": { $bitsAllSet: 65536 }}, 1, 0]} } but it errors with "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) based solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$flow"
}, {
    $facet: {
        "bitset": [{
                $match: { "flow.y": { $bitsAllSet: 65536 } }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                    y_total: {$sum: {$subtract: [ "$flow.y", 65536 ] }}
                }
            }
        ],
        "bitunset": [{
                $match: { "flow.y": { $bitsAllClear: 65536 } }
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                    y_total: { $sum: "$flow.y" }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```

Or without the `$group` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$flow"
}, {
    $facet: {
        "bitset": [{
                $match: { "flow.y": { $bitsAllSet: 65536 } }
            }
        ],
        "bitunset": [{
                $match: { "flow.y": { $bitsAllClear: 65536 } }
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        y_count_set: { $size: "$bitset.flow.y" },
        y_total_set: { $subtract: [ { $sum: "$bitset.flow.y" }, { $multiply: [ { $size: "$bitset.flow.y" }, 65536 ] } ] },
        y_count_unset: { $size: "$bitunset.flow.y" },
        y_total_unset: { $sum: "$bitunset.flow.y" }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the example. I was attempting to $unwind the results from the $facet sub-pipelines and perform the aggregation on those. Which wasn't working out.